# Operator overloading <

Tags: c++, object, operator-overloading, this

I'm trying to verify if the first object is smaller then the second object.
I'm getting error message the first is `areaCircle is not a type`.

```
bool Circle::operator < (const Circle & pc) const
{
    return *this.areaCircle(getradius) < pc.areaCircle(getradius) ? true : false;   
}
```

Here is my areaCircle function

```
float areaCircle(float radius){return( radius*radius*3.1416);}
```

Comment: areaCircle looks like a global function to me vs. a class member of `Circle`...

Comment: Operator precedence... `*this.areaCircle` should be `(*this).areaCircle`, but then that's simply `this->areaCircle`... (if `areaCircle()` really is a member function...)

Comment: No point in calculating area. The area is directly proportional to the radius. So just compare radii.

Answer (score 3):

`.` has precedence over `*`. You want `->`.

```
return this->areaCircle(getradius) < pc.areaCircle(getradius) ? true : false;
```

Or just leave out `this->` altogether (it’s implicit).

---

Also, since your `areaCircle` function doesn’t depend on the object’s state, you should consider making it a static member function or a free function.

Comment: ...and while you're at it, leave out the ternary operator: `return areaCircle(getradius) < pc.areaCircle(getradius);` Unless somebody's written an amazingly bone-headed overload of `operator<`, it should already yield a `bool`.